# Programmatically generated forgot password link showing expired

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to reset my password using below code,

```
$emailid  = $this->post('email_id');
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
            ->loadByEmail($emailid);
    if ($customer->getId()) {
        try {
            $newResetPasswordLinkToken =  Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
            $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
            $customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
            $this->response([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Email sent successfully'
                ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // NOT_FOUND (404) being the HTTP response code
        }catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->response([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Email ID is not registered with us.'
                ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); // NOT_FOUND (404) being the HTTP response code
        }
    }
```

Above code it's working perfectly, I am getting mail also, But when I click reset password button in the mail, Its showing link expired.

I have noticed the password reset link, they have used two parameters (id, token). In the programmatically generated email, the link has only token, id parameter is missing. I don't know why id not coming.

Can any one help help me to fix this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$emailid = $_POST['email'];
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($emailid);
if ($customer->getId()) {
try {
$customerId = $customer->getId();
$newResetPasswordLinkToken =  Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
$newResetPasswordLinkCustomerId = Mage::helper('customer')
                    ->generateResetPasswordLinkCustomerId($customerId);
$customer->changeResetPasswordLinkCustomerId($newResetPasswordLinkCustomerId);
$customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
$customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
}
catch (Exception $exception) {
Mage::log($exception);
}
```